# Apache HTTP Server has stopped working in Xampp

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

I am using LiteCart opensource e-commerce platform. When i run xampp server, apache and mysql server starts without any error and warning. But when i open browser and hit the url to open my installed litecart application it gives me an error

[image]

I also checked for online solution but nothing happened. 
Can anyone will help me in this.

Problem details:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH 
Application Name: httpd.exe 
Application Version: 2.4.17.0 
Application Timestamp: 561cc534 
Fault Module Name: php5ts.dll 
Fault Module Version: 5.5.37.0 
Fault Module Timestamp: 576b2166 
Exception Code: c00000fd 
Exception Offset: 0005a5ba 
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 
Locale ID: 1033 
Additional Information 1: 64c6 
Additional Information 2: 64c64714e3c644daeb62f47ad597dc84 
Additional Information 3: 36e8 Additional 
Information 4: 36e8add2564fc225e8a656ba7214b7ab
```

Comment: Did you look in the Apache Error log?

Comment: Did you look in the PHP Error Log?

Comment: Did you click on the `View Problem Details` on that dialog?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  `Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version: 2.4.17.0
  Application Timestamp: 561cc534
  Fault Module Name: php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.5.37.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 576b2166
  Exception Code: c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0005a5ba
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 64c6
  Additional Information 2: 64c64714e3c644daeb62f47ad597dc84
  Additional Information 3: 36e8
  Additional Information 4: 36e8add2564fc225e8a656ba7214b7ab`

Comment: when i click on view problem details i got this

Comment: Nobody can read stuff like that in a comment, In future, just edit your question to add additional information. I did it for you this time

Comment: I would start by checking what version of PHP you are running and then check the LiteCart site to see if the version of that will run on your version of PHP

Comment: You could also check the Windows Event Viewer for more information. Apache writes to that as well as its own log file sometimes there is more useful info in there

Comment: My PHP Version is 5.5.37 and LiteCart support this version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix this problem:

1. Stop the Apache web server from the XAMPP control panel
2. Choose `httpd.conf` from config menu on XAMPP control panel
3. Insert this code to the end of the file:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
  ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, It's a memory problem.

Search **“memory_limit”** in your **php.ini**, and change the value of it.

If no **“memory_limit”** found, add the following line at the end of **php.ini**:

```
memory_limit = 128M ; /* Change the 128M to your needs */
```

Save file.

Restart Apache.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of errors in you **java code**.

First of all check your tomcat or GlassFish logs.

Then just debug your code, and you will find your problem.

Comment: I am not using any java code. It is Php based application.

Comment: In the tags to this issue I see `tomcat`